# How would I convert this data from Little Endian to Big Endian

Tags: objective-c, endianness

I'm working on a solution that is outputting data in little endian, I need to convert it in objective-c, what's the best way to approach this.

Conceptually I understand what's going on, I'm struggling with the code to make it happen.

The data is being outputted in a CBCharacteristic.

UPDATE:

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error changing notification state: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {

        // Extract the data from the characteristic's value property
        // and display the value based on the characteristic type
        NSData *dataBytes = characteristic.value;
        if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:LOCK_OCCUPANCY_CHAR]]) {
            NSLog(@"%@",dataBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output from the log:
LOG: <79660000 7a660000 27671b80 0700>

Starting from left to right the values are represented as: **Start Time, End Time, Mac Address**.

The timestamps are in unix epoch.

Comment: Updated, any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your example above you seem to be reading some data from some device -- and the data is being packaged up in a single NSData buffer.   Since it's a known format - with a known size you can read it into a structure so you can access each field, and process if needed.

```
char rawData[] = {0x79, 0x66, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7a, 0x66, 0x00, 0x00, 0x27, 0x67, 0x1b, 0x80,0x07, 0x00};
NSData *sampleData = [NSData dataWithBytes:rawData length:sizeof(rawData)];

typedef struct MyStruct {
    uint32_t starttime;
    uint32_t endtime;
    uint8_t macaddress[6];
} MyStruct;

// first step - break the buffer into a structure

MyStruct sample;
[sampleData getBytes:&sample length:sizeof(sample)];

// second step - IF needed you need to process each member of the structure

// CFSwapInt32BigToHost is documented to take a known Big Endian (Network Order) to the format
// that the current CPU supports.   I'm not 100% sure that your sample data has reasonable timestamps
// so I can't verify if the sample data actually needs to be swapped or not

sample.starttime = CFSwapInt32BigToHost(sample.starttime);
sample.endtime = CFSwapInt32BigToHost(sample.endtime);
```

The act of changing from Little Endian to Big Endian is frequently called 'Byte Swapping' - you need to know the byte order of your current CPU uses (in theory that can change based on your hardware target) - with iOS, both the Simulator (x86) and the Devices (ARM) are both the same (Little Endian).

Since you mention using an Apple Framework, I'd recommend using Apple's CoreFoundation functions to do your work.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Tasks/ByteSwapping.html

Comment: Fantasic answer Todd, really appreciate the help.